# Basic PHP - HTML flow - high level understanding

Tags: javascript, php

Can someone confirm that the is the basic flow for PHP - HTML.

PHP runs on the server, and pre-processes the page so it can be sent to the browser.

In the browser you can run things like javascript.

So in order to pass things to PHP (from Javascript):

```
you need to "fetch" the php page (with post or get args)
This re-runs the php page (on the server) allowing you to process those args, generating a new "page" to send to the browser. 
PHP variables aren't "sent" to the browser, but processed and inserted in the a new page that's sent out when the page is fetched.
```

Am I even close ?

Comment: Php is server side language but js is client side, I think this is wrong place for that type of information so do search on google there are tons of videos and articles around. One of them https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction

Comment: hi andrew, welcome to stackoverflow. generally, for a starter in web development, i'd answer your question as a yes. PHP runs on the server while the Js **in** the web page runs in the web browser. However, as of now, people do run Js on the server too (because they can) as Dlk explained.